# In which Indian Institutions can I find Planetary Scientists or Planetary Geologists?

Tags: planet, planetary-science, geology

Which institutions in India provide labs and facilities for research in the field of Planetary Sciences/Planetary Geology?

Comment: Here is a potential list https://www.scimagoir.com/rankings.php?country=IND&area=1900&ranking=

Comment: another list: https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-institutions-in-india-to-pursue-planetary-science

Answer (score 4):

There are probably many, but I'll highlight one.  The Physical Research Laboratory has a [Planetary Research Division](https://www.prl.res.in/prl-eng/division/psdn).

> We study solar system objects, their atmospheres, surfaces and interiors, and governing processes using planetary exploration (i.e., spacecraft-based observations), laboratory experiments, physics-based theoretical/ numerical modelling, and computer simulations.

It is based on Gujurat Uni campus.